# AWS sentiment analysis gives different results on same string (R)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, sentiment-analysis

I have a data frame with Christmas song lyrics that looks approximately like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(line = c("I don't want a lot for Christmas", 
                           "There is just one thing I need", 
                           "I don't care about the presents", 
                           "Underneath the Christmas tree", 
                           "I just want you for my own"))
```

I've also installed the R package `aws.comprehend`.

I then turned this into one long string:

```
lyrics_df1 <- df1 %>% 
  iconv(., from = "UTF-8", to = 'ASCII//TRANSLIT') %>% 
  str_c(.,collapse = " ")
```

When I now run the code `detect_sentiment(lyrics_df1)`, the output is:

```
  Index Sentiment        Mixed Negative   Neutral   Positive
1     0   NEUTRAL 0.0003775794 0.291473 0.6762416 0.03190778
```

However, if I run the same code on just the lyrics as a string, I get the following output:

```
detect_sentiment("I don't want a lot for Christmas
There is just one thing I need
I don't care about the presents underneath the Christmas tree
I just want you for my own")

  Index Sentiment     Mixed  Negative   Neutral  Positive
1     0   NEUTRAL 0.2951728 0.2238117 0.3551461 0.1258695
```

The output is now totally different!

How can I make sure I am getting the same result as directly pasting the entire lyrics into the `detect_sentiment()` function?

Answer (score 2):

When you use the first command, you are sending the whole data.frame to the functions, this results in:

```
df1 %>% 
  iconv(., from = "UTF-8", to = 'ASCII//TRANSLIT') %>% 
  str_c(.,collapse = " ")
```

> [1] "c("I don't want a lot for Christmas", "There is just one thing
> I need", "I don't care about the presents", "Underneath the
> Christmas tree", "I just want you for my own")"

Probably the symbols addeds are causing this difference in the score. To apply the functions directly to the variable, use `pull`

```
df1 %>% 
  pull(line) %>% 
  iconv(., from = "UTF-8", to = 'ASCII//TRANSLIT') %>% 
  str_c(.,collapse = " ")
```

> [1] "I don't want a lot for Christmas There is just one thing I need I
> don't care about the presents Underneath the Christmas tree I just
> want you for my own"